# Why am I getting an error when it tries to read from the file?

Tags: java, cryptography, filereader, filewriter

I am writing a program that can encode and decode messages using classical encryption methods. The message is to be read in from a file and written to an output file. The following program is written in java and compiles with no errors. When I run the program to test if it works so far after I give it the names of the input and output file it runs into some kind of exception throwing error. I assume the issue lies in the for loop that follows in the code. It is a loop to store all of the message into an array of characters. Any suggestions to fix it or another data structure that would work better (like a stack or queue)?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class CryptoProject1
{
static char eord;
static Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
static char [] message=new char[10000];

public static void main (String [] args)
    throws IOException
{
    //getting the input txt file name from user
    String infilename;
    System.out.println("Please give the name of the input file.");
    infilename=cin.nextLine();
    Scanner fileread=new Scanner (new FileReader(infilename));  

    //getting the output txt file name from user
    String outfilename;
    System.out.println("Please give the name of the output file.");
    outfilename=cin.nextLine();
    PrintWriter filewrite=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outfilename));

    //saving the message into an array
    //construct/make it into a usable function??
    for(int i=0; i<message.length; i++)
    {
        message[i]=fileread.next().charAt(0);
    }

    //trial to make sure it reads and writes correctly
    //printing the message onto the output file
    for(int i=0; i<message.length; i++)
    {
        filewrite.print(message[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: "it runs into some kind of exception". What is the exception? It should tell you exactly what's going wrong, and where.

Comment: add in your first loop a check : if(fileread.hasNext()) and then do the action else break

Comment: @resueman this is the error message that it gives: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
        at CryptoProject1.main(CryptoProject1.java:112)

Answer (score 2):

```java
for(int i=0; i<message.length; i++)
{
  message[i]=fileread.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Here, you cannot know if file length is same or higher than message, file may as well have 10 characters. You need to do that:

```java
for(int i=0; i<message.length; i++)
{
  if(!fileread.hasNext())
    break;
  message[i]=fileread.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Just a simple check if there is still something to be read from file, if not then stop reading.

Also it is customary to use the Java object File to represent files rather than using string to hold the file path. Example:

```
private File output;
public void create file(String path)
{
    output = new File(path);
}

private BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
```

Comment: That fixes the error but now when it writes to the output file in only takes the first letter of each word and then a bunch of nulls behind it.

Comment: Well, you are reading file char by char, and it's quite hard with scanner (`next()` takes the next token, you are taking first character from it).

Comment: What I suggest: change `message` to list of Strings `ArrayList<String>` and add `fileread.nextLine()` to it. This requires few changes (you can't use size of it for reading file, because it's size is 0 after creation, you need while loop like `while(fileread.hasNext()) message.add(fileread.nextLine())`. Then you can write to file and loop using `size()` of the list. [Check this for reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also, whenever you write to a file, make sure you close it by calling the close() method or its contents wouldn't be saved

Comment: yeah, which means that there's probably an issue in the loop that reads the characters and assigns it to the array. It might have to do with the .charAt(0).

Answer (score 0):

```
//I ran this code without an error
//getting the input txt file name from user
String infilename;
System.out.println("Please give the name of the input file.");
infilename=cin.nextLine();
Scanner fileread=new Scanner (new FileReader(infilename));  

//getting the output txt file name from user
String outfilename;
System.out.println("Please give the name of the output file.");
outfilename=cin.nextLine();
PrintWriter filewrite=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outfilename));

//saving the message into an array
//construct/make it into a usable function??
for(int i=0; i<message.length; i++)
{
    if(fileread.hasNext())
    message[i]=fileread.next().charAt(0);
}
fileread.close();

//trial to make sure it reads and writes correctly
//printing the message onto the output file
for(int i=0; i<message.length; i++)
{
    filewrite.print(message[i]);
}
filewrite.close();
}
```

Comment: I made sure my code matched this exactly and it still only gives the first letter of each word and a bunch of nulls in the output... I'm not having troubles compiling it now, I'm having troubles getting it to work the way I want it.